# Does creating a Content Provider changes the default file permissions

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Since default file permissions in Android Linux kernel are not to share data between applications, does creating a ContentProvider change those permissions or it don't need to change them for allowing access, update, deletion of the application data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not need to change permission to file. If your content provider exported = true and other application call your content provider, then system call your content provider code, which running with under your user, with your permission. So this content provider has access to files of your application.